# EuropeCV fails with LaTeX2e pre-release because of loading hyperref in \AtBeginDocument

Tags: hyperref, package-writing, nameref, lthooks

Below is a minimal example that compiles successfully with stable TeX Live 2022 `pdflatex` but fails with the latest (and expected to be released in a couple days I think) `pdflatex-dev`:

```
\documentclass[nologo]{europecv}

\begin{document}

\begin{europecv}{}

\ecvpersonalinfo{}{}

\end{europecv}{}

\end{document}
```

With `pdflatex-dev` I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX hooks Error: Sorting rule for 'begindocument' hook applied too late.
(hooks)              Try setting this rule earlier.
```

I've reported this to EuropeCV
[here](https://github.com/gsilano/EuropeCV/issues/29) and the author kindly suggested they would consider a pull request. I also reported this at LaTeX2e [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/841), and received some helpful explanations and suggested fixes. In particular, Ulrike Fischer gave the following advice:

> Yes, don't load hyperref in begindocument. Use \AddToHook{begindocument/before}. Or alternatively load at least nameref earlier.

Unfortunately, I don't even know enough LaTeX to apply what seems to be a simple fix. I tried to <s>hack</s> experiment with [europecv.cls](https://github.com/gsilano/EuropeCV/blob/master/europecv.cls) (I was hoping to ask a question on tex.se that would just confirm that my "fix" was a reasonable hotfix), but could not make progress. The first thing I tried was to just put `\RequirePackage{nameref}` before `\RequirePackage{hyperref}` since that seemed to be the most simple fix from what I understood. I tried that loading of nameref inside the hook and before the hook, and neither worked. I then tried changing `\AtBeginDocument` to `\AddToHook{begindocument/before}` and that did not work either. Let me know if you want the logs of any of these attempts.

Note that I don't actually use EuropeCV so I'm not looking for a workaround to a apply to a .tex document.

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/242#issuecomment-1146813792

Comment: @DavidCarlisle was faster ;-) you must also handle utf8x, see https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/833. (Removing ucs/utf8x completly from europecv is the better fix.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks so much for all of your quick replies and help! Regarding removing ucs/utf8x, I just want to confirm that documents that load it manually that used to compile are now expected to fail. I asked this question at https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/242#issuecomment-1146813792. After that's cleared up hopefully we'll be done with this issue :)