# Document compile fails with latest europecv.cls

Tags: europecv

I tried to compile an europecv document, but it fails with

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty))

! LaTeX hooks Error: Sorting rule for 'begindocument' hook applied too late.
(hooks)              Try setting this rule earlier.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.421 ...begindocument}{showkeys}{before}{nameref}
```

error. The strange thing is that I tried to put the modifications David Carlisle recommended, and in the europecv.cls file there are no line containing the incriminated command, nor the lines David said to being modded... Now I laugh in agony, frome where is this error coming, and when I applies

```
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}%
\RequirePackage{hyperref}%
}%
```

the error remains.

Comment: "David Carlisle recommended" where? please give links and an example document

Comment: `\documentclass{europecv}
\begin{document} x \end{document}` gives no  error

Comment: you are loading hyperref too late (in the begindocument hook).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it errors for me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it is the class, I seem to have a fixed copy locally

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes it loads hyperref in begindocument.

Comment: @David Carlisle: That doc throws the same error for me. The recom is from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646747/europecv-fails-with-latex2e-pre-release-because-of-loading-hyperref-in-atbegind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appear to have a fixed copy of the class, presumably for a previous answer.

```
\documentclass{europecv}
\begin{document} x \end{document}
```

runs without error in a class fixed as follows

```
$ diff /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/europecv/europecv.cls .
10c10
< \ProvidesClass{europecv}[08/03/2022 (Unicode TeX detection) European curriculum vitae class]
---
> \ProvidesClass{europecv}[13/03/2022 (Unicode TeX detection) European curriculum vitae class]
264c264
<    \includegraphics[width=\ecv@logowidth]{europasslogo}}
---
>    \includegraphics[width=\ecv@logowidth]{europasslogo.eps}}
420a421,422
> %\RequirePackage{ucs}
> %\RequirePackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
448c450
< \AtBeginDocument{%
---
> \AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. Maybe I was lame, because I added the \AddToHook command after the \AtBeginDocument, today I exchanged...